# Is there a way to add more than one model to a class based view?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Is there a way to add more than one model to a class based view ?!

This is my detail view.

```
class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Article
```

I want to add another model to my view .

I know i can use function based views in order to to have multiple models in my view.

But i'm wonder that is there any way i can do this with my class based view ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you have to handle excess models yourself. If you want to show details of two separate models in one view, you will need to override `get_context_data`. Of course you will need to write your custom methods to fetch the object.

If it is ambiguous to determine which model is main model (meaning that the majority of the view revolves around it and the other models are just supplementary, for example: a user profile needs user model and may need other models such as posts or favorite post etc., In this case the main model is user model), you should really use TemplateView to handle all of them yourself, instead of DetailView or ListView.

[Check out this site](https://ccbv.co.uk/), which has plenty of info to see what methods does class methods have and how to override them.